# SQL calculate percent from categorical column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table

| Name | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Phil | Red |
| Phil | Red |
| Phil | Red |
| Phil | Blue |
| Joe | Blue |
| Joe | Red |

desired output

| Name | Color | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phil | Blue | 25 |
| Phil | Red | 75 |
| Joe | Red | 50 |
| Joe | Blue | 50 |

this is what I thought would work but does not for me

```
select Name, Color, count(color) / sum(color) as pct
from
group by Name, color
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to divide the count of the current value for the combination of `color` and `nam` (I always avoid potential reserved words for object names) by the count of the current value for `nam`. This can be solved by OLAP (window) functions with different `OVER()` clauses.

As OLAP functions return the same number of rows as the input, we need implicit grouping on all columns, hence a `DISTINCT` clause.

```
WITH
indata(Nam,Color) AS (
          SELECT 'Phil','Red'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Phil','Red'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Phil','Red'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Phil','Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Joe','Blue'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Joe','Red'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  nam
, color
, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY nam) AS nam_occ_count
, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY nam,color) AS color_count
,   100 
  * COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY nam,color) 
  / COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY nam) 
  AS pct
FROM indata
ORDER BY 3;
 nam  | color | nam_occ_count | color_count | pct 
------+-------+---------------+-------------+-----
 Joe  | Blue  |             2 |           1 |  50
 Joe  | Red   |             2 |           1 |  50
 Phil | Blue  |             4 |           1 |  25
 Phil | Red   |             4 |           3 |  75
```

Answer (score 0):

You need simple aggregation and the window function `SUM()` to calculate the percentage:

```
SELECT Name, Color,
       100 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) pct
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Name, Color;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5f1f12886f026a0bf1a13fc42f12bae).